# Игра змейка, неверно отображается голова змейки

Tags: c++, vector, sfml

при написании классической змейки с перемещением по сетке. Для начала генерирую и отрисовываю сетку, помещая каждую ячейку в вектор:
`

```
void GameGrid::fillingVector(sf::RenderWindow& window) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i <= window.getSize().x / sizeGrid; i++)
    {
        std::vector<sf::RectangleShape> subRow;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < window.getSize().y / sizeGrid; j++)
        {
            sf::RectangleShape rectangle(sf::Vector2f(sizeGrid, sizeGrid));
            rectangle.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(i * sizeGrid, j * sizeGrid));
            rectangle.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::White);
            rectangle.setOutlineThickness(2);
            rectangle.setFillColor(sf::Color::Black);
            subRow.push_back(rectangle);
        }
        gridMap.push_back(subRow);
    }
}

void GameGrid::drawGrid(sf::RenderWindow& window) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < gridMap.size(); i++)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < gridMap[i].size(); j++)
            window.draw(gridMap[i][j]);
}
```

`
Перемещение змейки реализовано по созданному выше вектору, путем изменения полей, хранящих индексы объекта головы:

```
void snake::SnakeHead::controlHead() {
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D) && direction != 'D') {
        
        direction = 'D';
        buttonPressFlag = true;
    }
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W) && direction != 'W') {
        direction = 'W';
        buttonPressFlag = true;
    }
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S) && direction != 'S') {
        direction = 'S';
        buttonPressFlag = true;
    }
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A) && direction != 'A') {
        direction = 'A';
        buttonPressFlag = true;
    }
}
void snake::SnakeHead::borderControl(std::vector<std::vector<sf::RectangleShape>>& gridMap) {
    if (this->getIndexI() >= gridMap.size() - 1 || this->getIndexJ() >= gridMap[0].size() - 1 ||
        this->getIndexJ() <= 0 || this->getIndexI() <= 0) this->startGameFlag = true;
}
void snake::SnakeHead::moveHead(std::vector<std::vector<sf::RectangleShape>>& gridMap){
    
    if (startGameFlag) {
        this->iIndexForGrid = (gridMap.size() - 1) / 2;
        this->jIndexForGrid = (gridMap[0].size() - 1) / 2;
        startGameFlag = false;
    }
    borderControl(gridMap);
    this->setPosition(gridMap[this->iIndexForGrid][this->jIndexForGrid].getPosition());
    if (direction == 'S') this->jIndexForGrid++;
    if (direction == 'W') this->jIndexForGrid--;
    if (direction == 'A') this->iIndexForGrid--;
    if (direction == 'D') this->iIndexForGrid++;
    Sleep(75);

}

void snake::SnakeHead::controlSnake(std::vector<std::vector<sf::RectangleShape>>& gridMap){
    
    moveHead(gridMap);
    controlHead();
    
    
    
}
```

Перемещение хвоста осуществляется путём присвоения предыдущих индексов головы хвосту каждую итерацию цикла.

```
void snake::CondtrolSnakeTail::addToMap( ) {
    Snake tail;
    tail.setSize(sf::Vector2f(25,25));
    tail.setFillColor(sf::Color::Yellow);
    tailMap.push_back(tail);
    
}
void snake::CondtrolSnakeTail::controlAllTails(int i, SnakeHead& head) {
    if (head.getStartGameFlag()) {
        tailMap[i].setIndexes(tailMap[i - 1].getIndexI(), tailMap[i - 1].getIndexJ());
        head.setStartGameFlag(false);
    }
    else
        switch (head.getDirection())
        {
        case 'D':
            tailMap[i].setIndexes(tailMap[i - 1].getIndexI()-1, tailMap[i - 1].getIndexJ());
            break;
        case 'A':
            tailMap[i].setIndexes(tailMap[i - 1].getIndexI()+1, tailMap[i - 1].getIndexJ());
            break;
        case 'W':
            tailMap[i].setIndexes(tailMap[i - 1].getIndexI(), tailMap[i - 1].getIndexJ()+1);
            break;
        case 'S':
            tailMap[i].setIndexes(tailMap[i - 1].getIndexI(), tailMap[i - 1].getIndexJ()-1);
            break;
        }
}
void snake::CondtrolSnakeTail::controlFirstTail(SnakeHead& head, int i) {
    /*if(head.getButtonPressFlag())
    {*/
        tailMap[i].setIndexes(head.getIndexI(), head.getIndexJ());
        /*head.setButtonPressFlag(false);*/
    /*}
    else
        switch (head.getDirection())
        {
        case 'D':
             tailMap[i].setIndexes(head.getIndexI() - 2, head.getIndexJ());
            break;
        case 'A':
            tailMap[i].setIndexes(head.getIndexI() + 2, head.getIndexJ());
            break;
        case 'W':
            tailMap[i].setIndexes(head.getIndexI(), head.getIndexJ()+2);
            break;
        case 'S':
            tailMap[i].setIndexes(head.getIndexI(), head.getIndexJ()-2);
            break;
        }*/
}





 void snake::CondtrolSnakeTail::moveTail(SnakeHead& head, sf::RenderWindow& window, std::vector<std::vector<sf::RectangleShape>>& gridMap) {
        
        for (size_t i = 0; i < tailMap.size(); i++)
        {
            
            if (i == 0) controlFirstTail(head, i);
            else controlAllTails(i, head);
            tailMap[i].setPosition(gridMap[tailMap[i].getIndexI([tailMap[i].getIndexJ()].getPosition());
            window.draw(tailMap[i]);
            
        }
            
        
    
    }

//snake.h
    class Snake: public sf::RectangleShape
            {
            protected:
                int iIndexForGrid = 0, jIndexForGrid = 0;
        
            public:
                void setIndexes(int i = 0, int j = 0) {
                    iIndexForGrid = i;
                    jIndexForGrid = j;
                }
        
                int getIndexI() {
                    return iIndexForGrid;
                }
                int getIndexJ() {
                    return jIndexForGrid;
                }
            };
        }
```

Отображение игры:

```
  #include "Game.h"
    void Game::start(int windowWidth = 500, int windowHeight = 400, std::string windowTitle = "Snake tail") {
        sf::RenderWindow window( sf::VideoMode(windowWidth, windowHeight), windowTitle );
        GameGrid grid;
        snake::SnakeHead snake;
        
    
        
        snake.setSize(sf::Vector2f(25,25));
        grid.fillingVector(window);
        snake.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
        snake::CondtrolSnakeTail tail;
        tail.addToMap();
        
        
        
        
    
        std::vector<std::vector<sf::RectangleShape>> gridMap = grid.getVector();
        while (window.isOpen()) {
            
            sf::Event event;
            while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
                if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                    window.close();
            }
            window.clear(sf::Color::Black);
            
            grid.drawGrid(window);
            
            
            
            snake.controlSnake(gridMap);
            tail.moveTail(snake, window, gridMap);
            window.draw(snake);
            
            window.display();
        
        
        
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что ховст змейки отображается перед головой (пробовал переворачивать всю сетку, результат тот же) присваивается всё верно хотя если вручную изменить строку

```
  `tailMap[i].setPosition(gridMap[tailMap[i].getIndexI()[tailMap[i].getIndexJ()].getPosition());`
```

на

```
`tailMap[i].setPosition(gridMap[tailMap[i].getIndexI()-2][tailMap[i].getIndexJ()].getPosition());`.
```

Пробовал в ручную изменять положение хвоста, подобным образом, оно работает но очень дёргано. Основной вопрос, с чем связанно такое отображение? Индексы в объектах хранятся верно.